# How to change Namespace of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, namespaces

I'm working on a library which uses jQuery internally which work fine. But I don't want force the user to use my jQuery version just because he uses my library in his code.

So the question is, how can I use jQuery under a different name?

Is it sufficient to do something like this:

```
var mylib.jQuery = {};  
mylib.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

This will make jQuery available under `mylib.jQuery` and free the `$` symbol, but the original `jQuery` symbol still works (which I think is not so good).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to go into the source because window.jQuery is defined there, and just update the reference name.

This seems like an unreasonable request though.

Edit: Looks like all you have to do is set the reference to $.noConflict:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
var foo = {};
foo.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict( true );
alert( typeof jQuery );
alert( typeof $ );
alert( typeof foo.jQuery );
</script>
```

You'd have to do this right after you include the script though. My previous way did it directly in the script:

http://173.45.226.115/jquery.html

Comment: Well, noConflict is sufficient for most I suppose, hehe. but yeah I'd update all window. statements in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

By specifying true in the `jQuery.noConflict(true);`, it sets the noConflict to extreme mode and should make it so it won't conflict with any other library. It should be the first thing you define anywhere I'm guessing, so no jQuery code/plugin should appear before the `var mylib.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);`