# Grails: Including JQuery Autocomplete in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, grails, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

i am working on a webapplication using Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.2.

I am trying to include JQuery autocomplete for multiple values: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

This is on order to allow the user to make multiple selections from a hasMany relationship between two domain classes.

I have tested the jquery autocomplete in a new grails project without bootstrap and it works perfectly.

However as soon as i include it into my project and add the bootstrap layout to the view in the header, the styling of the textfield is altered and the autocomplete function does not work anymore.

I therefore believe that it is related to the bootstrap styling of the textfield, but i dont know how to solve this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd use https://gist.github.com/1866577 instead of jqueryui's widget.  Having conflicting UI libraries is sure to cause you even more pain down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a conflict. I'd recommend looking at the browser console to see any error output.

If you find that you have a conflict, try changing the Bootstrap namespace:

**[Bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html)**

> "Sometimes it is necessary to use Bootstrap plugins with other UI
>   frameworks. In these circumstances, namespace collisions can
>   occasionally occur. If this happens, you may call .noConflict on the
>   plugin you wish to revert the value of."

```
var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict() // return $.fn.button to previously assigned value
$.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton            // give $().bootstrapBtn the bootstrap functionality
```

Alternatively, you could [change the JQuery UI namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535691/how-to-change-namespace-of-jquery). These two UI frameworks should play well together though. An example of this is the [JQuery UI Bootstrap](http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/) project.